# Tools can get full file path (including filename)

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, context-menu

OS: Windows XP SP3

Is there tool that can get the selected file full path (like c:\PathToFile\target.file) to clipboard? And which be added to windows file context menu. So that can get path by right click on the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File menu tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html) can do this (among many other things).

Comment: Sweet, this is it. But one more question is where in registry to modify the FileMenu Tools context menu, so I can have a keyboard navigation (underline).

For example, I want FileMenu Tools can be select by hitting 'F' and then copy path by hitting 'C'. Thanks.

Comment: This I don't know but you could try mailing the author at support@lopesoft.com.